# Storage getting blobs TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient, azure-blob-storage

My application uses Azure storage blobs in order to download files from remote storage to the local machine.

How it works:

1. The machine getting a queue message with URL (signed URL) to Azure Storage blob.
2. The application sending GET to download the file. It's done with `HttpClient`.
3. Application logic continues from there.

This is how I downloading the file:

```
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, signedUrl);
HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(msg);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

I found that few times per day, I got exception:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>        ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.
>        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operation canceled
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.g__InternalFillBufferAsync|38_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
>          at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
>          at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)

At this point, I must clarify that this behavior is happening to ~0.1% of the URLs passed in the system.

I was suspecting that the problem is with the signed-URL. I found in all cases the signed URL was correct - I just put it in the browser and it was working.

Now when I know that the problem is not the URL itself, I thought it can be a network problem. So, by using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) I have added 5 retries with an exponential delay between each one. Up to 5 retries. Delay formula - 3^n (where n is the number of retries). In the worst case, it will wait 4 minutes before trying again... And even now - still same error. All 5 retries were used but the file was not downloaded.

What to do? What else I should check?

Comment: What’s the size of the blobs that are failing?

Comment: around 3mb for a blob...

Comment: I noticed that you’ve set the timeout as 120 seconds. Can you try by increasing that to say 300 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a network issue. I suggest you use Azure Storage Client SDK to download blob.

```
// Blob SAS URL
string url = "https://storagetest789.blob.core.windows.net/devops/deploy.ps1?sp=r&st=2020-01-21T09:39:06Z&se=2020-01-21T17:39:06Z&spr=https&sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=tyGX6wpgAooOZK2Po2ntukF0fGx3PosSNTgkLlVysrE%3D";
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(url));
Console.WriteLine(blob.DownloadText());
```

You can also download to file or stream with SDK methods. The SDK may handle all the underlying stuffs.